# create pdf using reactor flux and openpdf

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, openpdf

I'm trying to create a pdf in memory using libre/openpdf (https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF) and spring's routerfunctions.

I have a Flux of `com.lowagie.text.Element` that contain the content of the pdf.

The `com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter` used, takes a `com.lowagie.text.Document` and an `OutputStream`. `Element`s are added to the `Document` and the data is written to the `OutputStream`.

I need the output in the `Outputstream` to be written to the body of the `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse`.

I tried to solve this using the following:

```
//inside the routerfunctionhandler

val content: Flux<Element> = ...
val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val document = Document()
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream)
document.open()

content.doOnNext { element ->
    document.add(element)
}
    .ignoreElements()
    .block()
document.close()
byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().toMono()
    .let { 
        ok().body(it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())) 
    }
```

The above works but has an ugly block inside the elastic thread and does not guarantee cleanup of resources.

Is there an easy way to turn the output of an `OutputStream` into a Flux of `DataBuffer`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `then(...)`-Operator as it lets the first Mono complete and then plays another Mono.

```
...
content.doOnNext { element ->
    document.add(element)
}
// .ignoreElements() // necessary?
.doFinally(signal -> document.close())
.then(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().toMono())
...
```

I think it should work without `.ignoreElements()`.

Comment: Ok, indeed, I implemented this using a variation of `Mono.using` to make sure the document is closed, combined with `then` to return the bytearray from the outputStream.